# xslt 1.0 escape apostrophe text with embedded html

Tags: json, xslt, escaping

I am trying to escape an apostrophe that appears in text which also contains embedded html tags.
My XML looks like:

```
<segment code="ASDF"> ...
<text> <a href="asdf.aspx?lfn=GYPT_0&amp;u=0" >[ blah] </a> 08:57:11 02 OCT 2013<br /><b>blah</b>  <br /> blah ...<br /><br /> About <a href="EEEERE.aspx?lfn=MAB_0&amp;u=0" ><b>breathing</b></a>:  blah 
you "can't do" an ...[ more of the same ] </text> </segment>
```

I can extract all of this content as a single string (including all of the html markup and contents thereof) with:

```
<xsl:template match="text" >
    , text:'<xsl:copy-of select='node()' />'
</xsl:template>
```

Note the apostrophes around the <xsl:copy-of /> - the product of this exercise is JSON, and of course, this particular JSON will fail due to the apostrophe in **can't**.

Thanx for trying to understand!!
The ultimate result I'm trying to accomplish would look like:

```
 text:'<a href="asdf.aspx?lfn=GYPT_0&amp;u=0" >[ blah] </a> 08:57:11 02 OCT 2013<br /><b>blah</b>  <br /> blah ...<br /><br /> About <a href="EEEERE.aspx?lfn=MAB_0&amp;u=0" ><b>breathing</b></a>:  blah 
you "can&apos;t do" an ...[ more of the same ]'
```

( I'm converting from xml (which contains html markup as a string) to a JSON object (containing the html-marked-up string), and since the *value* is a string, it's enclosed in single-quotes, so any embedded single-quotes need to be escaped for javascript, *in a form that the browser will show properly*. )

Michael - I've tried your code - copied and pasted into my stylesheet.  The product is always nothing - an empty string.  I've also tried using the translate() function like this:

```
translate(node(),"'","&amp;apos;"), which also produces an empty string.
```

The specific change I made to use Michael's solution in my stylesheet was to change:

```
<xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
to
<xsl:with-param name="string" select="node()"/>
```

The . doesn't work, because the translator sees the embedded html tags as additional nodes, so their content is not returned.  The node() statement (with <output = html specified) fixes this, but the only circumstances I've found in which node() will actually produce a non-empty string  is when it's in a <xsl:copy-of statement.  When its in a <xsl:value-of statement it returns an empty string.  And I can't write, for instance:

```
<xsl:with-param name="string" select="<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>" />
```

I've tried translate() various xsl:call w/ params, but in all cases, they fail because no content seems to be produced unless the <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/> operator is used, and this can't be used as an argument in a function like translate(), and can't be used as the source for a select="" statement.

How the heck can I do this?
thanx
r

Comment: Thank you for trying to understand.

Comment: What type is the result that you are showing us? It is neither well-formed XML nor HTML. If it is text, why does it contain (unescaped) markup? And what happened to the wrapping `segment` element? Is it *supposed* to be removed, or are you only showing us a partial result?

Comment: The result is a snippet of html, delivered to the page in a JSON-formatted string (along with a bunch of other non-textual content), to be inserted into a page by some javascript. What I'm showing is a complete example result. The example is only a fraction of the JSON being delivered.  All of the rest of the JSON is working fine.  Just escaping the apostrophes in this particular element.

Comment: "*What I'm showing is a complete example result. The example is only a fraction of the JSON being delivered.*" I am not sure how to read this. I suspect you may not be fully aware of how important context is in XSLT. What may work for a snippet in isolation, may not work for the same snippet in the context of a larger document. My (corrected) answer below assumes that is indeed your entire input/output. If not, you will have to make the necessary adjustments.

Comment: If you're producing JSON then the correct escape is `\'` rather than `&apos;` - you're escaping the single quote from the JavaScript/JSON parser, not the HTML one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***(edited in response to your clarifications)***

Your  attempt to convert `'` into `&amp;apos;` is a step in the right direction. However, you cannot use the translate() function for this. The translate function replaces each single character with another single character. In your example:

```
translate($string, "'", "&amp;apos;")
```

any apostrophe character in the input $string would be translated to an (escaped) ampersand (the first character in the replace string).

The tool that you need to use here is a recursive named template, that will replace each occurrence of an apostrophe in the input string with a string (of multiple characters) representing an escaped apostrophe.

And, since at the end you want the output to contain `&apos;` instead of `&amp;apos;`, you must write the result to the output with escaping disabled.

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text">
    <xsl:text>text:'</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text/text()">
    <xsl:call-template name="replace">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
        <xsl:with-param name="search-string">'</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="replace-string">&amp;apos;</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="replace">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="search-string"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace-string"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($string, $search-string)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $search-string)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$replace-string" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $search-string)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="search-string" select="$search-string"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replace-string" select="$replace-string"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to you example input:

**XML**

```
<segment code="ASDF"> ...
<text> <a href="asdf.aspx?lfn=GYPT_0&amp;u=0" >[ blah] </a> 08:57:11 02 OCT 2013<br /><b>blah</b>  <br /> blah ...<br /><br /> About <a href="EEEERE.aspx?lfn=MAB_0&amp;u=0" ><b>breathing</b></a>:  blah 
you "can't do" an ...[ more of the same ] </text> </segment>
```

will produce this **result**:

```
<segment code="ASDF"> ...
text:'<a href="asdf.aspx?lfn=GYPT_0&amp;u=0">[ blah] </a> 08:57:11 02 OCT 2013<br/><b>blah</b><br/> blah ...<br/><br/> About <a href="EEEERE.aspx?lfn=MAB_0&amp;u=0"><b>breathing</b></a>:  blah 
you "can&apos;t do" an ...[ more of the same ] '</segment>
```

If you don't want the `segment` wrapper element, add one more template to the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="segment">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="text"/>
</xsl:template>
```

to get this **result**:

```
text:'<a href="asdf.aspx?lfn=GYPT_0&amp;u=0">[ blah] </a> 08:57:11 02 OCT 2013<br/><b>blah</b><br/> blah ...<br/><br/> About <a href="EEEERE.aspx?lfn=MAB_0&amp;u=0"><b>breathing</b></a>:  blah 
you "can&apos;t do" an ...[ more of the same ] '
```

which I believe is equal to "*the ultimate result I'm trying to accomplish*", give or take a space.

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaFq

Comment: Thank you so much Michael.  Your approach worked.  I would have never figured it out.  And I think the xsltransform.net tool will be rather helpful in the future.  I think I figured out everything you did except for the @*|node() template - I don't quite understand how that works - it seems kind of like an overload on all templates - is that right?